# access cookies from email?

Tags: javascript, php, email, cookies

Is it possible to access cookies from an email? My fear is that one can for instance steal facebook login cookies simply by sending an email.

I know it's possible to redirect a user to an url without him to be aware of it. For instance, I used to display a 1x1 gif to redirect the user to a url (I used that to make email opening stats). What if on the target url I create a malicious js script: will I be able to access the user's cookies?

Or to put it differently, if there is a link in the email and the user clicks the link, is the target website able to access user's cookies?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940612/how-are-cookies-handled-by-email-clients); does anyone have more details on the subject?

@user3345621

Thanks for your answer, it seems correct to me.
But to take on the facebook example again, I have a couple more questions:

I may be wrong, but I think the cookie encryption does not help in this case.
The cookie encryption will help to hide the password in case for instance I access
your local machine and look in the cookies directly.
However, if I steel the encrypted cookie, I will be able to use them,
and let facebook do the uncryption work.
So in other words, I think it does not matter whether or not cookies are encrypted,
as long as the application (facebook in this example) will decode them for you.

Now, same remark about the fact that the cookie is recreated.
I think this is a direct consequence of using session_regenerate_id function.

But anyway, my understanding (which may be wrong) is that even if the cookie is recreated,
if the hacker send you a malicious email, he will get the newest version of the cookies
anyway since in the technique I'm describing, you're redirected to a malicious website,
so that website, when opening would have access to the current cookies (if possible).

?

Comment: Even if what you say was possible, you would only be able to access cookies belonging to your domain, so no way of stealing Facebook cookies.

Comment: @André yes, I figured that out when trying to perform an Xss attack against myself. Xss attack basically use document.cookie, which can only access the cookie of the same domain. So that's good news, and  I can relax now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to send me an email with the following image:

```
<img src="http://localwebsite/js.php" />
```

On my local machine, I created a page at this url:

```
http://localwebsite/js.php
```

Which would alert("something") using javascript.

Sending the email to myself, 
I expected that the mail client would open a web browser page and open the js popup,
but that's not the case at all.

What happened is that since it's not really an image,
my mail client (using mail on mac) did display a blue square exclamation mark, 
indicating that he could not display that image.
Even if I click on "load images".
Then nothing more happens: 
I presume the mail client goes to the url and tries to display the expected image in the message,
but since there is no image, nothing changes.
The url wasn't open in the browser at all, everything was done in the background.

Reading more about javascript in emails, it seems that generally, javascript is not interpreted at all
in emails.
I tested that too: sending an email containing:

```
<script type="application/javascript">alert("pou")</script>
```

Mail (mac) does not execute the script.

So to answer the question,

I believe that the only thing a hacker can do with mail is:

- sending a link, then if you click on that link, anything can happen
- create an image that he can use to track whether or not you've opened the mail

So if you're cautious enough, mail are'nt a big threat.
I was paranoid…

Answer (score 4):

I might be incorrect, since I'm fairly new to application security.

Here goes my best shot, concerning cookies now:

Cookies are domain specific (FACT), when you have a facebook cookie storing your user ID and your email (perhaps?) only the facebook domain has access to that cookie. Also, in most cases, the information in your cookie, especially in enterprise systems such as facebook, is encrypted, in other cases a hash is used to mask the information (Sort of fact).

So let's take facebook as an example, since they use a strong encryption format (FACT). If for instance you were able to get hold of a users facebook cookie, you would need to de-crypt the information to start off with, for it to be of any use to you. By that time a new cookie would have been generated (darn facebook adddicts).

Onto the security issue, if by some means you were able to get hold of a users cookie that does NOT belong to your domain, it would be a hack (do'h!), and you would need to check for any browser (Yes you should be exploiting the browser), that has such an exploit, or look for one yourself..

So here they are:

- Browser Exploit, hack a specific browser.
- De-crypt (or de-hash) the cookie, if it's encrypted.
- And do this all be for the cookie has expired.

And the world is yours.